# Ternary Operator if else if issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

Been staring at this for days and from everything iv found it should be working but always ends up with ''. I'm checking the price change that can be positive or negative, hence the >0 <0.

```
 {parseInt(item.CheeseBarrelChange) > 0 ? <i className={styles.up}></i> :
 parseInt(item.CheeseBarrelChange) < 0 ? <i className={styles.down}></i>  :''}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but this is some gnarly code to begin with which is why you don't see ternary operators much in the real world, especially doubly-nested. I think you should split that out to multiple lines at the very least and the error should be obvious.

Comment: Operators look okay, and the only condition under which you'd get `''` is when `item.CheeseBarrelChange` is 0, or is not a numeric string (in which case the `parseInt` produces the value `NaN`, upon which comparisons always return `false`)

Comment: @SrdjanGrubor it's within a return so cant do an normal if statement.

Comment: @Jeffha77 Normally, you would evaluate this before the return statement so that in the code you have here you would just be saying something like `{ someObject }` that would be either nothing or an `<i />` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking to is if I was getting NaN got me thinking, issue was with ParseInt, switched to parseFloat and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the ternary statement itself, and so if the conditions keep failing with numbers you presume to be above or below zero; ensure the `parseInt` result of `CheeseBarrelChange` is not `NaN`.

```js
function change(input) {
  const c = parseInt(input.value);
  const i = c > 0 ? 'up' : c < 0 ? 'down' : '';

  console.log({ change: c, icon: i});
}
```

```html
<input value="0" onchange="change(this)"/>
```

In order to check this, you may consider moving the statement into a function and using a regular if or switch statement.